# WPF ToggleButton disappear when checked if I use ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, togglebutton

There is something I'm missing but I do not understand what:

If I do this:

```
<ToggleButton Content="&#xEC92;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
```

The button [image: unchecked button] changes like this when pressed [image: checked button]

But if I change it using the template then it disappears:

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LargeIconStyle}" Text="&#xEC92;"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

Before check:[image: unchecked with template]

After check: [image: checked with template]

I cannot understand why. 
Can you help me?
The color of the checked button is the system one.

Just for your reference the styles are:

```
<Style
    x:Key="LargeIconStyle"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseIconStyle}"
    TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BaseIconStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I just copied your code into a test project to try it. The `ToggleButton` does not disapear for me. There must be something different in your project from what you have posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a `ControlTemplate` and the `Template` property. These are used for the UI and functionality of the control. So essentially, you're turning your control into a `TextBlock`.

Instead, you want to use a `DataTemplate` and the `ContentTemplate` property.